# Which data structure i should use for host.create method using Zabbix api?

Tags: c#, api, zabbix

I'm tying to call `host.create` method (Zabbix API) to add host to my monitoring system. The problem is that I can't format the data structure to suit the JSON request.
Here you can see how it looks like:
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/api/reference/host/create
The problem is in the interfaces part. Looks like it should be an array of Dictionaries like this: `Dictionary<string, string>[] hostInterfaces = new Dictionary<string, string>`. But Newtonsoft.Json library can't build a JSON request with this structure. What else can suit this situation?

Comment: interfaces should be a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`

Answer (score 1):

The hostinterface should be an array of objects (at least one) described in the [documentation of Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/api/reference/hostinterface/object).

Newtonsoft json supports the [serialization of collections](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm):

> ```
> Product p1 = new Product
> {
>     Name = "Product 1",
>     Price = 99.95m,
>     ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2000, 12, 29, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
> };
> Product p2 = new Product
> {
>     Name = "Product 2",
>     Price = 12.50m,
>     ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2009, 7, 31, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
> };
>
> List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
> products.Add(p1);
> products.Add(p2);
>
> string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products, Formatting.Indented);
> //[
> //  {
> //    "Name": "Product 1",
> //    "ExpiryDate": "2000-12-29T00:00:00Z",
> //    "Price": 99.95,
> //    "Sizes": null
> //  },
> //  {
> //    "Name": "Product 2",
> //    "ExpiryDate": "2009-07-31T00:00:00Z",
> //    "Price": 12.50,
> //    "Sizes": null
> //  }
> //]
> ```

You can adapt this example to build your host interface object, something like:

```
HostInterface int1 = new HostInterface
{
   type = 2,
   main = 1,
   useip = 1,
   ip = 192.168.1.1,
   dns  = "",
   port = 161
};

HostInterface int2 = new HostInterface
{
   type = 1,
   main = 1,
   useip = 1,
   ip = 192.168.1.1,
   dns  = "",
   port = 10050
};


List<HostInterface> HostInterfaces = new List<HostInterface>();
HostInterfaces.Add(int1);
HostInterfaces.Add(int2);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(HostInterfaces, Formatting.Indented);
```